# Морфемный разбор слова «запасать»

Tags: морфология, корень-слова

Меня зовут Мария. У ребенка во 2 классе задание: выделить слова, где есть буква ***а*** в приставке. Слово *запасать*. Я считаю, корень *запас*. Учитель говорит, что *-пас-* корень в этом слове.

Ответ учителя: "Мария Викторовна, добрый вечер! Отвечала Вам на ходу, поэтому коротко. Интернет я смотрела по поводу Вашего вопроса. Посоветовалась с коллегами. Всё-таки мы склоняемся к корню -пас-. Есть такие ситуации в языке, когда корень без приставок не образует слов, но приставки меняются, что позволяет утверждать, что в нашем случае можно выделить корень -пас-, как носитель значения сохранить, сберечь".

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146316/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 4):

Я уже отмечала этот вопрос как интересный, но мне сказали, что ничего такого в нем не видят. Нет, есть там интерес! Да по этому вопросу  можно даже целую школьную «диссертацию» написать.

**1. Какой корень в слове «запасать»?**

Если посмотреть разбор слов в сетевых источниках, то там все дружно утверждают, что это ***ЗАПАС***.  Например: [https://morphemeonline.ru/З/запасти](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%97/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
В то же время в глаголе «припасать» выделяется корень ***ПАС***. А почему?

**2.  О связанных корнях**

Такие корни действительно существуют, и их не так уж мало: https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/unikalnye-morfemy-svyazannye-korni-unifiksy

Но вот что интересно: иногда  один и тот же корень в одних словах является **связанным**, а в других — свободным. Это как раз наш случай.

**Почему же так?** Дело в том, что многое зависит от приставок. Иногда носители языка хорошо  видят их значение, в других же оно не проявлено ясно. Отсюда следуют и разные решения.

**3. О корнях в глаголах "запасти" и "припасти"**

Здесь надо использовать словари (толковый, словообразовательный, этимологический).

**Толковый словарь** (значения слов современной речи)

***ЗАПАСТИ***; св. что (и чего). Заготовить впрок. З. консервы, хлеб, крупу. З. уголь (угля). <Запасать  нсв.

***ПРИПАСТИ***,  св. азг. 1. Заготовить впрок; запасти. П. овощей, консервов, варенья на зиму. // Приготовить, держать наготове. П. для праздника, для торжественного дня. 2. что. Скрыть, отложить на какое-л. время, для какого-л. случая. П. новость, важное сообщение.

**ПАСТИ,** нсв. кого. 1. Присматривать за скотом и птицей во время выгона на подножный корм. П. гусей, коров, овец. 2. Жарг. Вести наблюдение, следить за кем-л. Я ее пас до самого выхода.

**Разбираемся с корнем ПАС** (он выделяется в глаголах *пасти* и *припасти*).

**Этимологический словарь Черных**: Пасти, в древнерусском языке с 11 века,  общеславянская основа ***pasti***, общеиндоевропейский корень ***pa***, есть соответствие в латинском языке со значением "пища, корма, фураж"; исторический корень ***pa*** также в словах питать, пища.

**О глаголе "запасти"**

**Словарь Шанского**: Запасти, общеславянское, префиксальное (приставочное) образование от *пасти* со значением беречь, хранить.

**Большой этимологический словарь русского языка**, составитель Климова М.В., 2013 год. Запасти, возникновение: 11 век, от общеславянского *пасти* (беречь)

Что ж, с глаголом "запасти" все ясно. Слово общеславянское/древнерусское, образовано не в русском языке (после XIV века), а раньше, поэтому мы не выделяем приставку ***ЗА*** (на уровне современного словообразования).

**О глаголе "припасти"**

А вот с этим глаголом полной ясности нет. Этимологические и историко-этимологические словари должны давать сведения том, **в каком веке и от какой основы**  образовано слово, на там это найти сложно.

**Словообразовательные** словари дают информацию о **современном** видении ситуации, но следует учитывать **разные мнения** лингвистов, да и общепринятая оценка может со временем **меняться**. Конечно, академические структуры регулируют эту проблему, в том числе в учебных материалах для школ и вузов, но в любом случае оценивать решение конкретных словарей, изданных в разное время и разными авторами, надо **очень осторожно.**

**Что здесь можно предположить?** Вероятно,  слово «припасти» образовано уже в русском языке (после XIV века), но каким способом? Может быть, ***запасти — припасти***, то есть это замена связанной приставки ЗА. Это очень возможно, причем значение приставки ПРИ (приближение) проявлено ясно. Или ***пасти — припасти***, но под влиянием "запасти" и со сходным значением. Имеется в виду, что современное значение "пасти" не имеет исторического значения "беречь, хранить".

Но в каком **официальном (академическом)** источнике можно найти точные сведения? Этот вопрос остается дискуссионным.

**4. Вывод**

В соответствии с учебными материалами в Сети: в глаголе "запасти" выделяем корень ***ЗАПАС***, а ***ПАС*** — это связанный корень. Для сравнения: в глаголе "припасти" выделяем свободный корень ***ПАС***.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, комментарии давать пока не могу. Поэтому вынужден прокомментировать вот эти слова в ответе Sharon –

> **О глаголе "припасти"**
>
> А вот это слово, вероятно, образовано уже в русском языке, но каким
> способом? В словообразовательном словаре Тихонова (и в других
> словарях) оно не находится.

– здесь.

У Тихонова в его «Словообразовательном словаре русского языка» есть и ***запасти***, и ***припасти***. См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня дома есть древний Школьный (гнездовой) словарь Тихонова (1990), там для глагола "пасти" нет "запасти" и "припасти. Нашла в сети rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/dictionary/morphemic-orthographic/index.htm Там так: Запасти(сь) запас/ти́(сь). Припасти(сь) при/пас/ти́(сь) [ср.: за/пас/ти́(сь)]. Но эта информация мне неясна. Как образованы оба глагола? И почему выделена приставка ЗА? Если Тихонов считает, что это свободный корень (в глаголе запастись), то я с ним не согласна. Да и в учебных материалах в Сети это не так.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните в ответе вашу точку зрения по всей теме: корень ПАС как связанный или свободный, словообразование глаголов, этимология, а также  ситуация в школе.

Answer (score 1):

*запас* - корень *запас*, на него можно навешивать все разумные приставки:

> дозапасы водохранилища сводят к минимуму влияние сбросов на водоем

> нужно перезапасать товары

Можно образовывать возвратный глагол

> Запас себе = Запасся

Можно образовывать прилагательные с особым смыслом

> Запасной
> (не путать со стандартным *запасенный*)

Имеются предложно-падежные выражения со словом запас и цельные словосочетания

> игрок запаса, про запас

Все это демонстрирует отдельную смысловую единицу (корень) у слова запас и отсутствие таковой у слова припас.
Со временем, возможно, образуются множественные распространения у *припаса* и тогда он станет корнем, особенно если изменит значение относительно уже имеющегося *запаса*. Так и образуются новые слова-корни в языке.

Comment: "Заприпасти" и "наприпасти" (http://my-dictionary.ru/word/53397/napripasat/).

Comment: Странная логика, получается если слово нельзя преобразовать - это корень? Зачем тогда нужен корень? То есть по такой логике слова не должны образоваваться, так как все образованные слова корнями не являются)

Comment: А перезапасти — это как? Выкинуть всё и запасти заново?

Comment: Наш запас испортился. Нужно перезапасти запасы

Answer (score 1):

> Меня зовут Мария. У ребенка во 2 классе задание выдел.слова, где есть
> буква а в приставке. Слово Запасать. Я считаю корень запас.

Ну а почему Вы так склонны считать? Давайте вспомним, что говорится о корнях слов в учебнике Вашего ребёнка.

Наверное, примерно так:

> Общая часть родственных слов называется корнем. Чтобы найти в слове
> корень, нужно подобрать родственные слова, выделить общую часть…

Какие можно вспомнить родственные слову ***запасать*** слова? ***Запас, запасти, запасливый, запасной…*** И если мы вспомним только эти слова, то безусловно общей их частью будем считать «запас», который и назовём корнем.

Но разве в русском языке нет слов ***припасать, припасти, припас*** и др., родственность которых перечисленным выше словам ощущает практически каждый русскоговорящий? И общей частью всех этих слов будет уже только «пас».

Такой корень – «пас» – и выделялся всегда в словах ***запас, запасать, припас***… На такой корень указывали и словари Панова и Текучева, Потихи, Баранова…

Такой корень фиксировался и Тихоновым в его «***Словаре-справочнике по русскому языку. Правописание. Произношение. Ударение. Словообразование. Морфемика. Грамматика. Частота употребления слов***», вышедшем в 1995 году…

А вот как ответила на заданный ей вопрос **справочная служба русского языка Грамоты.ру:**

> **Вопрос № 310578**
>
> Какой корень в слове «припас»? Раньше оно считалось однокоренным со словом
> «запас» и в обоих словах при их сопоставлении выделялся корень «пас» –
> в словарях Панова и Текучева, Потихи, Тихонова… А что сейчас – эти
> слова перестали считаться однокоренными? И если да, то в сопоставлении
> с какими словами современного русского языка можно продолжать в слове
> «припас» выделять корень «пас»?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Ответ был дан, по-видимому, по «Морфемно-орфографическому словарю» А.
> Н. Тихонова (М., 2002), то же в электронной версии словаря.  В 
> «Морфемно-словообразовательном словаре» И. В. Гурковой (М.,
> 2012) представлены слова *запасать* и, как производное, *запасаться*,
> в которых обозначен корень ***запас***-.
> **Однако более правильным представляется выделение в словах *запас, запасать, запасти* связного корня -*пас*-.** Тот же корень в словах
> ***припасти, напасти***, а при более этимологичном подходе еще и *спасти, спасать*. Такая точка зрения представлена, кроме упомянутых словарей Б. Т. Панова — А. В. Текучева и З. А. Потихи, в
> информационно-поисковой системе «Орфографическое комментирование
> русского словаря».
>
> **Более того, можно предположить, что в «Морфемно-орфографическом словаре» А. Н. Тихонова содержится опечатка или ошибка**. Так, в
> статьях *припасти, припастись и напасти, напастись* содержится отсылка
> к *за/пас/ти, за/пас/ти/сь*. В  «Словообразовательном словаре русского
> языка» А. Н. Тихонова (М., 1990) статьи запасти, припасти, напасти
> снабжены перекрестными отсылками. Ср. статьи
> «Морфемно-орфографического словаря»:  запас | запа'с/ запасти |
> запас/ти' напасти1 | на/пас/ти'1 [ср.: за/пас/ти']  напастись1 |
> на/пас/ти'/сь1 [ср.: за/пас/ти'/сь] припасти | при/пас/ти' [ср.:
> за/пас/ти'] припастись | при/пас/ти'/сь [ср.: за/пас/ти'/сь]
>
> http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=310578