# Актуальное морфемное членение

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Хотелось бы обсудить с участниками идею актуального морфемного членения слова. Возьмём две цепочки:

1)След - следовать - на-след-овать - на-**след**-ник.

2)Наслед-овать - **наслед**-ник (придерживаются такого разбора Тихонов, Панов, Потиха).

Повторюсь, какое вариант с точки зрения **современного членения** вам кажется наиболее верным и почему?

Comment: Обсуждали тысячу раз подобные контрпары как следовать/наследовать, запас/припас, настрой/настройка. Не буду повторяться просто кину ссылку на свое полное исследование этого вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474051

Comment: @user190920 Там тоже ни к чему не пришли в итоге. Да и тут другой случай. Корень-то не связанный.

Comment: @user190920 к тому же в случае с "припасом/запасом" решение не в вашу пользу. Ответ давали филологи из ИРЯ: корень "пас".

Comment: Случай тот же. Припас/Запас - оба корни несвязанные. Наследник/Подследник - оба корни несвязанные. Что там пару человек решили 50 лет назад, меня не волнует, я говорю о тенденциях в языке и механизмах корнеобразования, они в мою пользу. Хотя у меня тоже можно важность аргументов подкручивать и получать тот или иной результат. Так что решить можно и сейчас по-разному. Встать с левой ноги и решить понимаешь, запротоколировать в пас, и повторять на каждом углу.

Comment: Нет. Никаких разных решений здесь быть не может. Ответ дан, и он верный: корнем может быть только часть "пас".  К тому же он связанный, т.к. в слове "пасти" представлен омонимичный корень.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, так: **наслед/овать** — **наслед/ник** (придерживаются такого разбора **Тихонов**, Панов, Потиха).

Корень ***НАСЛЕД***-, собственное словообразовательное гнездо.  Почему? А все по то же причине — приставка ***НА*** со значением **направленности**.

***НА***. 1. Указывает на направленность  **действия** в сторону  **предмета.**

В какую сторону? В сторону правовых отношений собственности **в соответствии с родственными отношениями.**

**НАСЛЕДОВАТЬ**, -дую, -дуешь; св. и нсв. (св. также унаследовать). что (от кого). 1. **Получить — получать** в наследство **в соответствии с правом наследования.** Н. землю, недвижимое имущество. Н. титул. Н. от старшего брата его капиталы.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

***НАСЛЕД-*** можно считать **словообразовательным формантом,** который имеет значение корня для определенной группы слов.

В этом случае приставка ***НА-*** модифицирует корень, придавая ему значение **направленности,** которого в самом корне нет.

Answer (score 0):

На/след/ник - от наследить.

> НАСЛЕДИТЬ
> где или на чем, наследовить пск., твер. натоптать следов, набегать, покинуть следы..
> Наслед жен. следы от грязных ног. Наклал в избе наследей. Наследях нареч., пск., твер. живым, свежим, поличным следом, по горячим следам. Наследие, наследье, наследство ср. имущество, переходящее, по смерти одного владельца, к иному, по родству, завещанью или по закону. Наследье ни дар, ни купля. Наследовать что от кого или по ком, или церк. наследити, быть наследником, иметь право на наследство или получать его; оставаться владельцем имущества по смерти кого. Сын наследует отцу, но отец не наследует сыну. Даль.

Comment: Следить на полу нельзя.  Потому что так не говорят. Правильно: наследить. Поэтому корень НАСЛЕД-   Это как бы не корень, а словообразовательный формант, высокая философия!  Потому что не всем доступная))

Comment: @Sharon и что, что не говорят, от этого корень как-то меняться должен? Корень первичнее любого "словообразовательного форманта". Я понимаю, когда в слове зонтик выделяют суффикс и получается зонт, ну бывает, слово не русское, а тут слово как бы русское. Наследить - наделать следов. Следить на тоже говорят, когда это слежка за кем-то. Тут речь не о том, можно или нельзя, положение предлога определяет кто следит, а за кем следят.

Comment: Есть на_след, например, напасть на след, навести на след, тот кто напал - следит, тот кто оставил следы - наследил. Наследник, наследие, наследство - оставленный кем-то след. Предлог определяет ньюанс значения, характер действия или взаимодействия слов-корней. Просто след - это вообще любая метка оставленная кем-то, наблюдаемое явление, все что угодно, что можно наблюдать. Наследник, наместник - одинаковые слова по типу образования.

Comment: Наследник - тот кто идет в след или во след. Идет по тому же пути. Наследник престола, прямой наследник - это вообще слово тяготеющее к причастию наследующий. На следующий день.

Comment: Please, выберите по толковому словарю нужное значение приставки НА. Как с ее помощью от "след" можно образовать "наследовать"? Я вижу только наследить – это везде и много натоптать. Можно сказать: здесь кто-то наследил к двери?  Думаю, что нет.

Comment: @Sharon вступать в на+следство ~ ступать след в след, ступать на след - идти по чьим-то следам, пользоваться проложенным кем-то путём. 1)Словари отражают общие моменты по использованию большинства элементов как приставки, но это не значит, что там есть прямо все и отражена вся логика. 2)словари вторичны по отношению к языку. 3) современные словари использую современную логику в соответствии с современной концепцией языкознания, а она не всегда была такой и она не единственная.

Comment: И не плизкайте мне). 4) слово наследник очевидно русское, полностью сочетающееся с корнем след по логике, а не как зонтик, так что не нужно выдумывать новые корни там, где их нет и быть не может.

Comment: Я вижу только наследить – это везде и много натоптать. - дак у кого какое наследие, кто сколько натоптал, столько и есть. Вы немного отвалитесь от вещественных следов. След - это любое явление или эффект, по которому можно установить связь с тем, кто его оставил. Не обязательно грязь от ног.

Comment: Я и говорю: высокую философию словообразования трудно бывает понять, уж очень она далеко от приземленности))  И не ругайтесь на меня, понеже сегодня день народного единства.

Comment: Понеже, хорошо, не ругаю, нежного вам дня народного единства)